# How to overlay an image over a background in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, overlay

I have an image in which certain pixels are black. And I also have a background image over which I want to overlay my image. But I want the background to appear only where the pixels are black in the main image. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your images are the same size, this is pretty easy. Suppose you have two images in grayscale, `mainImage` and `backImage`. Then you can set the `mainImage` pixels that are black to `backImage` values by writing:

```
mainImage(mainImage == 0) = backImage(mainImage == 0);
```

and this will set the `mainImage` black pixels `backImage`.

If the images are in color then you have to be a bit more careful. The easiest, most understandable way to do this in my mind is to find the zero values in each color plane and then set the `mainImage` where they are all zero to the `backImage`. I made a little messy very that converts to linear space and sets the pixels as follows:

```
[Ny, Nx, Nz] = size(mainImage);
dSize = Ny*Nx;

% Get the location of the black pixels:
bR = mainImage(:,:,1) == 0;
bG = mainImage(:,:,2) == 0;
bB = mainImage(:,:,3) == 0;

blackPixels = find(bR & bG & bB);

mainImage(blackPixels) = backImage(blackPixels);
mainImage(blackPixels + dSize) = backImage(blackPixels+dSize);
mainImage(blackPixels + 2*dSize) = backImage(blackPixels+dSize*2);
```

Comment: My images are in color. Will this work if my images are not of the same size?

Comment: For color you can use the second part. If the problems are a different size  then you will have to  translate the location of the black pixels from the main image of main size into the corresponding location in the background image of background size using `sub2ind`. You must be careful that if the background image is smaller than the main image that you don't try and access a location beyond the edge of the background image.

Comment: The background image is the bigger image. I resized the background image using `imresize` and it worked. Thanks.